# How to put MKMapView in a UIView - or initialize it in a frame with a custom size. RubyMotion iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, rubymotion

I'm trying to create a map using `MKMapView` but I only want it to take up half of the screen in the UI.

I'd like the map to be visible in half of the screen and also have the `long/lat` marker remain in the center of the visible map.

I've tried creating the map with `CGRectMake` and `CGRect.new` as well as creating a specific `UIView` and assigning it with `addSubView` with no luck.

This is what I'm working with:

```
def viewDidLoad
    self.view = MKMapView.alloc.init

    region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(@lat, @long), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0075, 0.0075))

    self.view.setRegion(region, animated:true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by moving the map layer into a method - I verified that the below works:

```
def loadView
  super
  # grab height / width
  @height = view.frame.size.height
  @width  = view.frame.size.width
  # this is your map layer
  mapRegion
  self.view.addSubview(@containerView)
end

def mapRegion
  @map_view = MKMapView.alloc.init
  # place map on top half of the screen
  @map_view.frame = [[0, 0], [@width, @height / 2]]
  self.view.addSubview(@map_view)
end
```